# Приватный чат на ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Не получается реализовать приватные комнаты для чата, что бы только пользователи чьи эмейлы указаны могли заходить и просматривать данный чат.

Использую Ruby on rails, на данный момент в БД есть такие данные :

```
<Chat id: 7, private: true, title: "Private Chat", created_at: "2016-01-25 08:50:03", updated_at: "2016-01-25 08:50:03", user_id: 1, privatemail: "darelvc@gmail.com, istokvc@gmail.com">
```

Есть текстовое значение поля privatemail

```
"darelvc@gmail.com, istokvc@gmail.com"
```

Те пользователи с эмейлами, которые заранее приглашены в комнату.

С помощью метода split я могу создать массив

```
chat.split(", ").uniq!
```

На выходе получим такие данные

```
["element@gmail.com", "darelvc@gmail.com"]
```

Теперь нужно сделать выборку элементов из массива и проверить или эмейл пользователя подходит к тем что указаны в массиве

Выборку думаю можно реализовать так

```
chat_new = chat.privatemail.split(", ").uniq
 => ["darelvc@gmail.com", "istokvc@gmail.com"] 

2.2.1 :020 > chat_new.all? {|element| chat_new.include?("darelvc@gmail.com")}
 => true
```

Но не могу понять, как правильно сделать и интегрировать этот код в ruby on rails приложение

Мой **chat.rb**

```
class Chat < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :messages
end
```

Мой файл **message.rb**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :chat
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Мой файл **user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :chats
  has_many :messages
```

end

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать код, чтобы это могло заработать или хотя бы подскажите наброски куда копать

Просто набросал такой код, не рабочий конечно, но думаю что возможно нужно сделать что-то схожее, хотя я конечно же не уверен.

```
def private_chat
    if @chat.private? == true
      @chat = @chat.privatemail.split(", ").uniq
      if @chat.all? {|email| @chat.include?(current_user.email)} == true
        @chat = Chat.find(params[:id])
      else
        redirect_to chats_path, notice: "You must be invited to this chat room"
      end
    else
      redirect_to chats_path, notice: "You must be invited to this chat room"
    end
  end
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Думаю, вам стоит **нормализовать** связь между чатами и пользователями, потому что в таком виде в БД обрабатывать выборки с её участием будет **тяжело**, на грани невозможного, даже если забыть об ActiveRecord и вооружиться сырым SQL. Если термин **нормализовать** вам незнаком, раскрываю мысль: между чатами и пользователями, видимо, должно быть отношениие многие-ко-многим. Я пока подожду с ответом, возможно, вы захотите существенно изменить вопрос.

Comment: Немного добавил информации по вопросу

Answer (score 1):

Может кому поможет.

Решение оказалось банальным, я просто добавил еще 1 поле в таблицу chats, а именно public со значением false, true

И в контроллере в show разделил так

```
  def show
    if @chat.private?
      if @chat.private_users.find_by_email(current_user.email) != nil || current_user.admin?
      #if @chat.private_users.all? {|email| @chat.private_users.include?(current_user.email)} == true
        @messages = Message.where(chat_id: @chat)
      else
       redirect_to chats_path, notice: "You must be invited to join this chat room"
      end
    end
    if @chat.public?
      @messages = Message.where(chat_id: @chat)
    end
  end
```

Вот и все =)